# Web Audio AudioBufferSourceNode detune VS playbackRate

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Is there any difference between AudioBufferSourceNode detune and playback rate? Both seem to have the same effect.

I have been experimenting with playing a sample at a lower pitch but trying to keep the duration the same as the original. I thought this could possibly be achieved with a combination of these two values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detune does the same thing, its value is in cents. On a western music scale there are 100 cents per a half step. This makes it easy to calculate note differences.

If you want to change pitch while keeping the original speed you will need to implement a *pitch shift* algorithm on the audio buffer material.